# Which Surah ends with the name of two Prophets?

Tags: quran, ayah

Which ayah of the Surah in the Quran that ends with the name of two Prohpets ?

Comment: If downvoters mention the reason. I would be happy to correct myself.

Comment: This question shows absolutely no research effort; what are you hoping to find that can't already be found in a [basic search?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Which+Surah+ends+with+the+name+of+two+Prophets%3F&t=canonical). Please also go through [ask].

Comment: @BleedingFingers Thanks, I can find that first link (this question) is gives me answer and other link does not even talk about it or it doesn't gives correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surah No : 87 -  Surah Al-A'la (The Most High)

Ayah 19 -> The Scriptures of Ibrahim (Abraham) and Musa (Moses).